# Is there a way to convert a base64 encoded string into 8-bit ASCII in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, ruby, encoding, multipartform-data

I'm writing code in Firebase functions that acts as an intermediary between two databases. (I've been mandated to do it this way.)

I need to send some user data and some PDFs over from Database 1 to Database 2. I have everything working except for the PDFs. There are PDFs with the right number of pages in Database 2, but the problem is that the PDFs show up blank in the user portal and when I download them from the database.

Database 1 sends me a base64 encoded string for the PDF. I don't know what exactly I'm supposed to send to Database 2. Database 2 has an API and very sparse documentation in Ruby; they only provide examples, and there is little support for the API. Below is the part I haven't been able to figure out so far:

```js
post_body << "--#{BOUNDARY}\r\n"
post_body << "Content-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"document[attachments_attributes][0][attachment]\";
filename=\"document.pdf\"\r\n"
post_body << "Content-type: application/pdf \r\n"
post_body << "\r\n"
post_body << File.read(file)
post_body << "\r\n--#{BOUNDARY}--\r\n" # the last boundary is prefixed and suffixed
with --
```

The part I don't really know is `File.read(file)`. I don't know how to get the equivalent of whatever that method returns in a NodeJS environment from a base64 string. I tried `File.read(file).encoding` in IRB and it returned UTF-8, so I tried `Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64').toString('utf8')`, but that didn't work.

I've tried every encoding I could pass in that method ('ascii' (7-bit), 'utf8', 'utf16le', 'latin1', 'binary', 'hex' -- nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_array). None of them work. I tried converting a UTF-8 string to a string of JavaScript escape sequences. I tried [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-1252). I googled [common encodings in Ruby](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-steps-to-fix-encoding-problems-in-ruby/) and saw that 8-bit ASCII was one of them, so now I'm trying to convert base64 to 8-bit ASCII in NodeJS.

If you have an idea of what I'm not doing correctly, that'd be great. Or if you don't but have an idea of how to convert base64 to 8-bit ASCII, that'd be great too.

Below is a snippet of what File.read(file) returns in IRB:

```js
Creator(շ\x8Fc\\(t~\xC8\u0018\u0005\xA6\x8F\xB8\xD2\u0017\x8C\u0014\x87b\u0004\xE8\xB4ΐ<Έ\b)/Producer(շ\x8Fc\\(t~\xC8\f\\(\x93\xB6\xB0\xD5\u001E\x9BF\x90{\u001A\xF6\xAD\xFB\xE8\xD0\xEB\xD9\u0005ŕ\ew\xF3)/ModDate(\xD0\xEE\xCF<z-:\xDExu\xD1\xF7\xED\x8EA\xC8\u0019\x80{\u0013\xF6\xB3\xE9)/Company(ӻ\x8Bi8{g\x8D&5\xC0\xAD\xBF\x99+\x8B_\xDF\")/SourceModified(\xD0\xEE\xCF<z-:\xDExu\xD2\xF0\xED\x8BG\xC8)/Title(\xB4\x84\xB9JjAo\x9B<a\xB0\xA3\xBE\xDC)>>\rendobj\rxref\r\n0 37\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000014115 00000 n\r\n0000014965 00000 n\r\n0000014998 00000 n\r\n0000015021 00000 n\r\n0000015072 00000 n\r\n0000019484 00000 n\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535 f\r\n0000000000 65535
```

It looks like some ASCII characters with some escape sequences to me.

Below is more of the example, in case you need it:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "net/http"
require "time"
require "digest"
require "openssl"
require "base64"

# Token used to separate each Content Part. This string should be a
# random string and not appear in the file body.

BOUNDARY = "MultipartBoundary"
uri = URI.parse "https://kipuapi.kipuworks.com/api/patients"
file = "spec/fixtures/files/document.pdf"

post_body = ""

post_body << "--#{BOUNDARY}\r\n" # boundaries are prefixed with --
post_body << "Content-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"document[data][first_name]\"\r\n"
post_body << "\r\n"
post_body << "John"
post_body << "\r\n"

post_body << "--#{BOUNDARY}\r\n" # boundary's prefixed with --
post_body << "Content-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"document[data][last_name]\"\r\n"
post_body << "\r\n"
post_body << "Smith"
post_body << "\r\n"

post_body << "--#{BOUNDARY}\r\n"
post_body << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"document[recipient_id]\"\r\n"
post_body << "\r\n"
post_body << @access_id # sending to ourselves
post_body << "\r\n"

post_body << "--#{BOUNDARY}\r\n"
post_body << "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"app_id\"\r\n"
post_body << "\r\n"
post_body << @access_id
post_body << "\r\n"

post_body << "--#{BOUNDARY}\r\n"
post_body << "Content-Disposition: form-data;
name=\"document[attachments_attributes][0][attachment]\";
filename=\"document.pdf\"\r\n"
post_body << "Content-type: application/pdf \r\n"
post_body << "\r\n"
post_body << File.read(file)
post_body << "\r\n--#{BOUNDARY}--\r\n" # the last boundary is prefixed and suffixed
with --

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.body = post_body
request["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data, boundary=#{BOUNDARY}"
request["Accept"] = "application/vnd.kipusystems+json; version=1"
request["Date"] = Time.now.httpdate
request["Content-MD5"] = Digest::MD5.base64digest request.body
canonical_string = [
 request["Content-Type"],
 request["Content-MD5"],
 uri.request_uri,
 request["Date"]
].join ","
digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new "sha1"
signed = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest digest, @secret_key, canonical_string
encoded_sig = Base64.strict_encode64 signed
19 / 23
request["Authorization"] = "APIAuth #{@access_id}:#{encoded_sig}"
response = http.request request
puts response.body
```

Here is part of the relevant code in Firebase (note that at the time, I wrote one function to handle all get and all post requests thinking this was going to be a small project, which I now regret),

```js
function createReq(uri, body, credObj, method, multipart, res){
    if (multipart){
        let postBody = '';
        let dataObj = body.document.data;
        let attachmentsArr = body.document['attachment_attributes'];

// formatting data in dataObj, appending to postBody

        for (let i = 0; i < attachmentsArr.length; i++){
            postBody += '--'+BOUNDARY+'\r\n';
            postBody += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; ';
            postBody += 'name="document[attachments_attributes]['+ i +'][attachment]'+'"; ';
            postBody += 'filename="'+ attachmentsArr[i]['filename'] + '"\r\n';
            postBody += 'Content-type: ' + attachmentsArr[i]['content_type'] +' \r\n';
            postBody += '\r\n';
            
// TODO: need to do something with the base64 attachment string here               
            //console.log(attachmentsArr[i]['attachment']);

            if (i === attachmentsArr.length - 1){
                postBody += '\r\n--'+BOUNDARY+'--\r\n';

            }
        } // closes attachmentArr loop

// authentication code, define variables signature and contentStr

        let reqObj = {
            url: ROOT_URL+uri,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data, boundary='+BOUNDARY,
                'Accept': ACCEPT_HEADER_VALUE,
                'Authorization': 'APIAuth '+credObj.accessId+':'+signature,
                'Date': new Date().toUTCString(),
                'Content-MD5': contentStr
            },
            body: postBody
        };

        return reqObj;

    } else // other code for non-multipart post requests
}
```

The returned reqObj gets sent to Database 2 in my promise: 
(I've commented out the code that sends my request to Database 2 for now)

```js
...

}).then(reqObj => {

// code for get method
// ... 

else if ('POST' === method){
    reqObj.method = 'POST';
            console.log('THIS IS REQUEST OBJ INSIDE LAST PROMISE');
            console.log(reqObj);
        //     request.post(reqObj, function(error, response, body){
        //         if (!error){
        //             console.log('THIS IS RESPONSE FROM KIPU');
        //             console.log(body);
        //             res.send(body);
        //         } else {
        //             console.log(error);
        //             res.send(error);
        //         }
        //     });
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        res.send(err);
    });
```

Comment: FWIW there is no such thing as '8-bit ASCII'. ASCII itself is only 7 bits, however there are *other* 8-bit encodings that are *ASCII-compatible*.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this! I was going by this page (http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-steps-to-fix-encoding-problems-in-ruby/), which calls it "ASCII-8BIT". I've also heard of Extended ASCII (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII). I'm looking for anything that might shed some light on what I need to do to get this working.

Comment: Also, why not just use a node module (e.g. `request`) to handle the multipart and http request instead of trying to do it all yourself? [Firebase functions can use modules from npm](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/dependencies#loading_nodejs_modules).

Comment: The code in Firebase does use the request module to make the request to Database 2; I'll update the post to include that part of the code. I do still need to put the body of the request in a format that the API will accept.